# NewBie: C++ Private Variables

Tags: c++, function, get, private

So im learning c++ and my teacher was saying that you need intGetFoo() functions in order to return the private data . So for example i have this code

```
class Pseudorandon{

public:
   Pseudorandon( int Seed,int Multiplier,int Increment,int Modulus);
   void PerformAlga(int a, int b, int c, int d);
   void GetOutput();

private:
  int seed;
  int multiplier;
  int increment;
  int modulus;
  int Number;
  int Number2;
  int Number3;
  int Number4;
};
```

**Main**

```
Pseudorandon::Pseudorandon(int Seed,int Multiplier,int Increment,int Modulus){
  PerformAlga(Seed, Multiplier, Increment, Modulus);
}

void Pseudorandon::PerformAlga(int a, int b, int c, int d){
  seed=a;
  multiplier=b;
  increment=c;
  modulus=d;
}

void Pseudorandon::GetOutput(){
  Number =  (multiplier * seed + increment) % modulus;
  Number2 = Number;
  Number3 = (multiplier * Number2 + increment) % modulus;

  std::cout<<Number<<Number3;
}

int main(void)
{
  Pseudorandon ps(1,40,725,729);
  ps.GetOutput();
}
```

So what is the point of having `intGetFoo()` if I can get the data that is private using public function from my class without using a GET function.

When would I use getters i.e (`intGetFoo(){return private variable}` ).
function or what are there purpose??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need getters and setters if you need to access data from outside the class. In your case it might be so you could say

```
  std::cout << "Output from seed=" << ps.GetSeed() << ", muliplier=" 
            << ps.GetMultiplier() << " = " << ps.GetOutput();
```

You don't need to use getters and setters from inside `GetOutput`

Comment: Alright i Understand now, I misunderstood my professor. So anytime you want access to the information inside the class to lets say output in my main function i need Getters in order to get whatever that number is in this case if i was to write GetSeed() in my main function i could say          `             std::cout<<"when seed is this number"<<GetSeed()<<"this happens"<<ps.GetOutPut();                                                                                                    `

Comment: Yep - if you want private data outside the class - getters and/or setters. If it really is private to the class then you don't need 'em.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point using GetFoo from inside GetOutput. Either you misunderstood what your teacher meant, or he doesn't know what he is talking about.

The point of public/private is to hide the implementation of your class from the users of your class. But when you are writing the methods of your class you are implementing it, not using it, so there is no problem using private members directly.

Answer (score 0):

Private members are generally part of your internal state. Neither class users nor children class can access it. Typically `seed` in your case.

Sometimes, you may want to give access to the children classes and the class user a read-only access to part of your internal state: that's when you would use a getter!